# The wizened mathematician

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

*Once I walked up a hill, and on the summit sat a very old man cross-legged, calmly taking the air and observing the view below.  I asked him if he was alone and he said:*

"No.  I have five cousins who are coming up after me.  What is interesting about them superficially is that if you take their ages, each one being a double-digit integer, between them they include all of the digits 0 to 9.

But if you look deeper you will see it is even more remarkable: each pair of integers within the set is not coprime, that means they have a greatest common divisor that is 2 or more."

"Very interesting indeed" I replied.  "But what can I ask is the closest gap between the ages of your cousins?"

"4 years" he replied.

**How old are the five cousins?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cousins are

> 34, 51, 68, 72, and 90.

Pairs are divisible by

> 2, 3, or 17.

I hunted for

> Primes with multiples consisting of 3x is  and some x is  or , such that f(x)+4 was divisible by 3. This seemed the most likely approach to find a solution, as it would allow a variety of combinations to post-fit test for coprimality.

Comment: Did you also demonstrate that no other solutions are possible?  (Wondering.)

Comment: By computer I checked that the solution is unique. There are many solutions with other minimum differences: $(diff,\#sol)\in\{(3,71),(4,1),(6,92),(7,2),(9,72),(12,57),(14,42),(15,9),(16,38),(18,16),(22,1)\}$. The unique solution with a difference of 22 is $\{10,32,54,76,98\}$.